# Laravel eloquent for the combination of two tabels

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am new to laravel and using laravel 8. I have following tables and I am not able to understand how to establish eloquent relation between them.

Table - Fabrics

| id | user_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | fabric 1 |
| 2 | 1 | fabric 2 |

Table - Mesh

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | mesh 1 |
| 2 | mesh 2 |

Table - Designer

| id | user_id | mesh_id | fabric_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | designer 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | designer 2 |

I have done all the basic relations. Each designer has one mesh and one fabric. there is a unique combination of fabric_id and mesh_id in designer table meaning one fabric and one mesh can not have more than one row. now I want the list of fabrics with the sublist of meshes with which designers are created. basically from the designers table instead of
with(designers) I want with(meshes). Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: just to understand your problem domain, you have designers who can pick many fabrics and for each fabric there can be a list of meshes, is that right?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: @AnuratChapanond Sorry for unclear explaination. I have updated the original question, still pasting here. - Each designer has one mesh and one fabric. there is a unique combination of fabric_id and mesh_id in designer table meaning one fabric and one mesh can not have more than one row

Comment: @jeremykenedy I have build the basic relations which means I have already read this docs.

Comment: got it, then what you want is to extract which fabric is being used with which meshes from the designer table?

Comment: @AnuratChapanond Ok, so I want list of fabrics first. and it that fabric is used to create 5 different designer then I want all 5 meshes which are used to create that designer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a many to many relationship problem. See this [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships)
There is a good example on many to many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You have a many to many relationship between fabrics and mesh table with designer table being the intermediate table linking both tables together.

Therefore you should already have meshes relationship in your fabrics table using `belongsToMany(Mesh::class)` and have fabrics relationship in your mesh table using `belongToMany(Fabrics::class)`.

You can retrieve all the fabrics and its related meshes through its relationship.

```
$fabrics = Fabrics::get()

foreach($fabrics as $fabric) {
   $fabric->meshes
}
```

Comment: Meshes are not user specific so if I use `belongToMany(Fabrics::class)` in mesh model then it will give results for all users when I want it for specific user. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Since designer is the intermediate table, it works both ways. you can start from fabrics or meshes. if you do $mesh->fabrics you will get all fabrics that are associated through designers. Look at pivot in the Laravel doc if you want a specific designer.